# How to reset the scrollHeight values on DOM elements retrieved using ClientFunction

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have TestCafe running in two separate test classes, in two separate fixtures, in two separate tests, testing two different app pages.

I notice when I interrogate the `window.document` object through the `ClientFunction` in these tests, depending on the running order, I get differing values.

e.g.
mytest1.js

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

  fixture `Homepage`
    .page `http://mypage.com`;

  test('Test 1', async t => {

    const getBodyHeight = ClientFunction(() => window.document.body.scrollHeight);
    console.log(await getBodyHeight()) // 800px

  });
```

mytest2.js

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

  fixture `Dashboard`
    .page `http://mypage.com/dashboard`;

  test('Test 2', async t => {

    const getBodyHeight = ClientFunction(() => window.document.body.scrollHeight);
    console.log(await getBodyHeight()) // 1200px

    });
```

If I run these using `npm run testcafe -- firefox:headless mytest*.js` and the order is smaller height to larger height, the console will log:

```
...
800
...
1200
```

However if I run these the opposite way (larger height to smaller height), I get:

```
...
1200
...
1200
```

It is as if the `document.body` is stretched to a max value and doesn't return.

Is there a way using the `ClientFunction(..)` or possibly some other means to reset these values correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test scenario with `ClientFunction(() => window.document.body.scrollHeight)` looks correct. I prepared a small example and I can't reproduce this behavior. Does the following example work as expected on your side?

**index1.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

</body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
test
</html>
```

**index2.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

</body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
test
</html>
```

**test1.js**

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `My Fixture`
    .page `./index1.html`;

test('test 1', async (t) => {
    const getBodyHeight = ClientFunction(() => window.document.body.scrollHeight);

    console.log('test 1 body.scrollHeight', await getBodyHeight());
});
```

**test2.js**

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `My Fixture`
    .page `./index2.html`;

test('test 2', async (t) => {
    const getBodyHeight = ClientFunction(() => window.document.body.scrollHeight);

    console.log('test 2 body.scrollHeight', await getBodyHeight());
});
```

Results:

1. `testcafe "firefox:headless" tests/test1.js tests/test2.js`

```
 My Fixture
test 1 body.scrollHeight 932
 √ test 1

 My Fixture
test 2 body.scrollHeight 1762
 √ test 2


 2 passed (0s)
```

2. `testcafe "firefox:headless" tests/test2.js tests/test1.js`

```
 My Fixture
test 2 body.scrollHeight 1762
 √ test 2

 My Fixture
test 1 body.scrollHeight 932
 √ test 1


 2 passed (0s)
```

See also: [ClientFunction Object](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/)

Comment: yes it does work.
I then thought it was an issue with SPA's (we're using `create-react-app`) but that seems to be working fine also :frustrated: ...

my exact issue is on a production web app built on top of an internal component library so i'm thinking its quite possible one of the library components is not resetting the body and not testcafe